# Rails 4 and Locomotive cms workarounds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, locomotivecms

I want to try Locomotive CMS, while I was installing it, I realised that only runs with rails 3+ version no 4.
As I am currently working in a couple of other apps in rails and I am pretty new to it, I was wondering if is there any way to run one version of rails for locomotive and another one(rails 4) for my other apps. If so how could it be done?

Thanks in advance.

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definetely want to start using [rvm](http://rvm.io). It will help you not only separate your gems for different projects, but also separate and manage your Ruby versions. Definetely a great tool.

Comment: I actually found out that they have released a version for rails 4 now. In case someone getting here with the same question > https://locomotive-v3.readme.io/docs/getting-started-with-locomotive